# Gradle exclusion of transitive dependencies not working

Tags: gradle, dependencies

I have the following in a `subprojects` closure:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jersey-bundle'
}
```

But `gradlew dependencies` is still including `jersey-bundle`. What needs to be done to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that at the time the `configurations` closure is executed, `all` has no configurations. Use:

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.sun.jersey', module: 'jersey-bundle'
}
```

Comment: This works for me if I only have one exclude.  If I add more than one, then only the first one is processed.  its very odd, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Deny and Exclude rules from [Resolution Rules Plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-resolution-rules-plugin) can be used for this purpose. It provides a way to reuse the rules so not every project in the company must know the exact incantation needed to exclude dependencies.